# TFS 2018 Doesn't recognize agent capabilities

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

TFS 2018 build won't run because it says it can't find an agent with the needed capabilities even though I have an agent setup with all the necessary capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was creating a custom capability but didn't save it correctly.  All I needed was a capability called `Xamarin.Android` so I created this custom capability but when I created it, I didn't know I also had to set a value for it before the `Save Changes` button will become clickable.  After I put in a dummy value for `Xamarin.Android` it let me save changes and then the build worked.